# Can we embed a stand alone Java game into a webpage?

Tags: java, opengl, servlets, awt, java-web-start

I'm new to Java development and my requirement is to create a Java game that I need to run on a web server (eg. tomcat) not on client machine. Can I first develop a stand alone Java game and then embed it into a webpage using servlet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is Java based, it can either be embedded in a web page (applet) or launched from a web page.

It should be possible with this code:

```
<APPLET ARCHIVE="jar.jar"CODE="class.class" WIDTH=400 HEIGHT=200></APPLET>
```

**Width/height:** The measurements (in pixels) of the window.

**jar.jar:** your Jar (Export your project as one)

**class.class:** your main class

Comment: I read "When a user views an HTML page that contains an applet, the code for the applet is downloaded to the user's machine."

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_applet_basics.htmI 

I don't want the code to be downloaded to client machine.

Comment: I dont really know what this means, it could mean that parts of the program are downloaded to the users cache to run but it still would run it without the user to open it

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried making a java applet?

Or if you have your .jar file,

put this inside your html,replacing my_applet with your jar file name

```
<APPLET ARCHIVE="my_applet.jar" 
 CODE="my_applet.class" WIDTH=400 HEIGHT=200>
</APPLET>
```

For this your jar file must contain my_applet.class

Comment: I read "When a user views an HTML page that contains an applet, the code for the applet is downloaded to the user's machine." <br><br> 
tutorialspoint.com/java/java_applet_basics.htmI 

<br><br> I don't want the code to be downloaded to client machine.

Comment: You can put code like this at the beginning of the applet's init method, assuming it creates some components:

if (!getDocumentBase().getHost().equals("yourhost.com")) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "You can't download it");
    return;
}
Of course, you have to change yourhost.com to your actual website.